# GPS glitch causes 200 m circles around stationary position- Has anyone seen this before?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, gps, accuracy, tracking

I am working with GPS data from public transport buses in a city in the UK. The data have very characteristic circles of approx. 200 m diameter at bus stops. I suspect that these are caused by an estimated position but I do not know enough about the GPS technology to explain these patterns. **Have you seen these patterns before?**

The image shows GPS positions for several months. The white circle is the outbound bus stop and all points in yellow are outbound vehicles and inbound vehicles are shown in blue.

[image: GPS positions for inbound (yellow) and outbound (blue) buses. The light circle is the outbound bus stop.]
If the vehicle lost signal and estimated its position ahead I would expect a ring only in the direction of travel but I am getting one in both directions. These rings are always oriented in the direction of the route.
They also do not occur at traffic lights and pedestrian crossings, which would be explained by the fact the vehicle does not always stop in the same place as is the case at bus stops.

Just looking at the outbound direction the data looks like this, where the arrow shows the direction of travel.

[image: A randomly picked bus stop in the outbound direction with the arrow indicating the direction of travel.]

For a randomly picked example the percentages of the data points in the circle are:

- ~52% in the centre
- ~32% behind the bus
- ~15% in front of the bus

Even though this example is from a city, we are talking about houses on either side of mostly 2-3 storeys. So no skyscraper-canyons that could seriously impact the signal. Unfortunately, I do not know the exact GPS unit used or even where it is placed on the vehicle. For all I know, it might be installed under the driver's seat...

Below you can see an overview. with the stops highlighted in red and it the coordinates in white. These circles appear practically all along the journey at most of the 42 bus stops.

[image]

Any help explaining these circles would be amazing!

EDIT:
As suggested by [jgm_GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/37418/jgm-gis) I have colour coded the points based on

(distance from prior point) / (Time elapsed).

The results are not that clear (I guess they never are...) but it appears that in some cases the ratio is indeed higher in front of the vehicle and lower behind. (See example A&B). But in other cases, the difference is marginal at best or not existent and the ratio is virtually the same before and after vehicle (Example C).

The image shows the colour coded ratio with the approximate values for either semi-circle next to it.

[image]

Can anyone explain the intuition behind this? Essentially this shows the speed between the last two points. So what is the software doing? It moves the points away from the bus if it is close to the stop but not quite there yet?

Comment: Could GPS Multipath be the cause?

Comment: I  don't think so as it happens at virtually all stops (there are 42 of them) and always in the same orientation with the same diameter. I would expect a multipath interfernce to be more random?

Comment: I have added an overview of a larger section of the route where you can see the circles along the route.

Comment: If in a built up area your getting gps bounce (Multipath). The reflected signals of buildings/trees/hard surfaces cause this - see the image https://argustracking.zendesk.com/hc/article_attachments/360000129835/Multi_path.jpg

Comment: A35 Bocombe has high buildings > https://www.google.com/maps/@50.7221828,-1.8701912,3a,75y,66.21h,76.89t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1smoyxdcJn9JXZBBntMNRs0A!2e0!3e11!7i13312!8i6656 .

Comment: Do the vehicles' antennas have shielding to block low-angle signals?

Comment: With multipath problems I would expect that the artefacts are "random" noise around the position rather than a circle. Something like this https://file.scirp.org/Html/3-8501076/fe0e889e-c560-44e8-89f5-379c8787f5f1.jpg The other thing I would expect is that we would see the same error along the route. But it appears the the positions between the stops is much more accurate and the buildings around those areas are the same height.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know if there is a a shielding installed or not. Could this cause these circles?

Comment: Could it be that the GPS unit estimates the next position based on the bearing and the speed?

Comment: You could make a temporal analysis on these points: is there multiple points at the same time, indicating that two technologies could be involved, maybe a GPS on the bus and another fixed length captor located on the bus stop? Is the sampling rate constant, or is there some anomaly within the circles?

Comment: Does this happen on other routes and with more than one bus?

Comment: Yes that happens on all routes in several cities so it is not a single faulty GPS or similar. I know that the on board hardware uses geofencing to decide whether a bus has been at a stop or not. This uses a certain radius around the stop. Perhaps the position is projected by the software onto the boundary in some cases. I will do a temporal analysis and see what that might bring up.

Comment: I would create two maps to see if the software is moving the points. Try color coding the points using the (distance from prior point) / (Time elapsed). If the software is moving the points, I would expect to see a pattern of high values for points in front of the bus stop and low values for points behind the bus stop. You could try overlaying that layer with a map of segments created from pairs of points, ordered by time. If the software is moving the points you will probably see a lot of segments from the 200m boundary to the stop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input I will do that and give you an update once I know more.

Comment: I have plotted the ratio (distance from prior point) / (Time elapsed)  as suggested and updated the answer. Not 100% sure what the software is doing yet.

Comment: The legend shows negative values.  Are points jumping from one end of the circle to the other?  What does the map look like if you use the absolute value of the distance.  Also, can you highlight the points sequentially, one at a time, to see if multiple points are being moved to the 200m border.

Comment: The reason for the negative values is that I have used a trajectory to calculate the distance along the route. That means a negative value does indicate a jump against the direction of travel. Some small ones are expected from normal noise but I am guessing it could mean that the position of the vehicle is projected from the centre of the circle back against the direction of travel. I am just calculating the haversine distances and see what that looks like. I will look into highlighting the sequential points that might be a bit more complicated due to the data-structure.

Comment: Do you know what the geofence size is? If it is snapping points within the boundary to the stop, that might account for the gaps and the big sets of points before/after the stop. Or some other oddity with the geofence.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am suspecting that the buses are held on the geofence until they are directly at the bus stop. I am just trying to generate a synthetic dataset to see if that will create the same patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has taken quite some time to investigate but I think I have a working hypothesis that explains the strange circles. I found data for another city that uses different hardware and the circles are not seen in those. So it is a software problem.

As mentioned before a geofence is used to decide if a bus has been at a bus stop or not. So what I think is happening is that the software keeps the location on this geofence until it is directly at the bus stop. There is no good physical explanation for the seen phenomenon, so it has to be caused by a software issue.

---

### Simulating the stop behaviour

To test this I have simulated this with a data generator and it looks strikingly similar. For the simulation I did:

- generate a circle around the bus stop as an  example with a 50 m radius
- If a position was within the circle within 10 m of the bus stop I did not modify them
- If the position was inside the circle but further away than 10 m from the bus stop the position was changed to the closest point on the circle.

The schematic looks like this:

[image]

---

### The results

When simulating the data we get similar circles (the data generator does still need some work) and it looks quite similar:

[image]

Considering that this data is simulated with a not fully finished data generator I think this explains what is happening. Whether the position on the circle is chosen by picking the closest or slightly different I cannot say at the moment.

So as a conclusion this particular tracking hardware moves bus locations onto a geofence around stops unless they are directly at the stop. I would assume this has to do with the arrival time prediction. A possible explanation could be that the displayed arrival time at a stop gets confused if the vehicle is too close. But it could also just be a glitch. I have asked the company for comment but nothing so far. What I know is that data collected with hardware from a competitor does not have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's expected behaviour, for example the below GPS tracks from me working in woodland over a 3.5 hour period.  Green/Black lines are actual paths, and blobs are where the GPS was stationary.

[image: GPS tracks]

Comment: This is exactly what I would expect  some random noise around a stationary position. But the difference in my data is that we see the random noise as in your example with a very distinct circle around it. That should not happen with some "normal" inaccuracies.

Comment: I'm not sure what a normal inaccuracy is; every reading is a random error around a point location, some seem more accurate because you know the location.    Probably wrongly, I always thought you'd get a normal distribution around the point, so a circle seems correct.

Comment: This paper shows you can get ellipses [Characteristics of GPS positioning error with non-uniform pseudorange error](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10291-013-0359-z)

Comment: Yes that is what I would expect but it should be a random distribution round or maybe elliptical. But you would get points in the entire shape and not just on the boundary circle as in the images of the data.